# Difference between var Foo struct and type Foo struct

Tags: go, struct, var

I have hard time to understand what is the diffrence between:

```
var requestPayLoad struct {
        Email string `json:"email"`
        Password string `json:"string"`
    }
```

and:

```
type jwtUSer struct {
    ID        int    `json:"id"`
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
}
```

one is type and one is a var.

Comment: Try using them in your code and it'll be very clear. Hint: what if you want to reuse the type of variable `requestPayLoad`?

Comment: The first defines a variabel, the second a type. Take the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [`var v T`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) creates a variable, binds the identifier `v` to it, gives it the type `T`, and then initializes it to the *zero-value* of `T`.
- [`type t T`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_declarations) binds the identifier `t` to type `T`.

In both cases type `T` may be a named or an unnamed (anonymous) type.